# Is there any better way to handle list of countries along with their State/Privince/Region?

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I have web application where I have DropdownList of Country and also dropdownlist for State/Province/Region.

If I select country then its related state\province\region should be populated dynamically.

Population is easy thing.

But how and where should we maintain this huge data along with internationalization

Comment: Is this for mobile? or what? I would use mongoDB to store it based on not knowing anything else of your situation cause maybe you are booting a program off a floppy disk? they are slow

Comment: Not for mobile it is for Spring based web application

Answer (score 3):

```
step 1 : create data base for country names and related state names
step 2 : make ajax call on select box for country on onchange event
step 3 : the ajax call hits the db and return with the state names
step 4 : set the value for state select box with the received response from ajax call
```

Comment: I have done same thing but I need Country and state list. Can I have ready-made database available for Country and state provience list

Comment: @VinayakKedge : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463004/free-sql-script-to-get-a-list-of-countries-provinces-states-and-their-cities